# Call laravel naming routes from vue axios

Tags: php, laravel, vue.js, routes

Thinking is that any way to call the routes from route files with their names and get the url to axios in vuejs.

I don't know is it possible or not. If not please suggest me some other way to get the routes which i declared in laravel routes php files. Thanks

Answer (score 1):

One solution would be to do a `Route::getRoutesByName` which will return all your routes keyed by the name you provided. You could create a route that returns that route collection.

See the API here:
https://laravel.com/api/5.7/Illuminate/Routing/RouteCollection.html#method_getRoutesByName

Comment: Thanks. let me try this

Answer (score 0):

```
    <script>
  window.routes = {
    'users' : '{{ route('users') }}',
    'contact' : '{{ route('contact') }}',
  }

  // You can access it like this
  let route = window.routes.users
</script>
```

Comment: thanks for your answer. is their any way to get the routes without call all the routes separately and allocate it